# how to create folder in zip file archiver - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip, directory, archive

I want to create a `zip` file and new `folder` in it.
I created a zip file but couldn't create folders.

Here is my `node.js` code;

```
var archiver = require('archiver');
var zip = archiver('zip');

for(var i=0; i < files.length; i++){
     zip.append(new Buffer(files[i].data.buffer), { name: files[i].name } );    
}
```

For example I want to create folder as `/first/second` and add file in it.

```
.zip
  first(folder)
     second(folder)
        file
```

How can I do it?

Comment: are you sure that zip module you are using is meant for editing zip archives. this is what the documentation says "An implementation of unzip in JavaScript for Node"

Comment: I use for `archiver` for zipping yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, I just realize that it was quite simple by editing the name field in the following line;

```
zip.append(new Buffer(files[i].data.buffer), { name: files[i].name } );
```

as

```
zip.append(new Buffer(files[i].data.buffer), { name: "/folderName/" + files[i].name } );
```

You can replace `/folderName/` with any filename that you want to create.

Comment: Perfectly working!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp

Node Module that creates folders

Comment: But how am I going to create folder in zip folder?